# NSNumberFormatter PercentStyle decimal places

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I'm using Swift

```
let myDouble = 8.5 as Double

let percentFormatter            = NSNumberFormatter()
percentFormatter.numberStyle    = NSNumberFormatterStyle.PercentStyle
percentFormatter.multiplier     = 1.00

let myString = percentFormatter.stringFromNumber(myDouble)!

println(myString)
```

Outputs 8% and not 8.5%, how would I get it to output 8.5%? (But only up to 2 decimal places)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To set the number of fraction digits use:

```
percentFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
percentFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
```

Set minimum and maximum to your needs. Should be self-explanatory.

Comment: And for up to 2 decimal places, set `percentFormatter.maximumFractionDigits` to `2`. `8.5` will display as `8.5`, but `8.534` will display as `8.53`.

Comment: don't forget to set 'multiple' otherwise it will show 8.5 as 850.0

Answer (score 9):

With Swift 5, `NumberFormatter` has an instance property called [`minimumFractionDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1410459-minimumfractiondigits?language=objc). `minimumFractionDigits` has the following declaration:

```
var minimumFractionDigits: Int { get set }
```

> The minimum number of digits after the decimal separator allowed as input and output by the receiver.

---

`NumberFormatter` also has an instance property called [`maximumFractionDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1415364-maximumfractiondigits). `maximumFractionDigits` has the following declaration:

```
var maximumFractionDigits: Int { get set }
```

> The maximum number of digits after the decimal separator allowed as input and output by the receiver.

---

The following Playground code shows how to use `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` in order to set the number of digits after the decimal separator when using `NumberFormatter`:

```
import Foundation

let percentFormatter = NumberFormatter()
percentFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.percent
percentFormatter.multiplier = 1
percentFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
percentFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let myDouble1: Double = 8
let myString1 = percentFormatter.string(for: myDouble1)
print(String(describing: myString1)) // Optional("8.0%")

let myDouble2 = 8.5
let myString2 = percentFormatter.string(for: myDouble2)
print(String(describing: myString2)) // Optional("8.5%")

let myDouble3 = 8.5786
let myString3 = percentFormatter.string(for: myDouble3)
print(String(describing: myString3)) // Optional("8.58%")
```

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, look in apple documentation for [minimum fraction digits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1410459-minimumfractiondigits) and [maximum fraction digits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1415364-maximumfractiondigits) which will give you these lines you have to add before formatting your number:

```
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
```

Also notice, your [input has to be 0.085 to get 8.5%](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/style/percent). This is [caused by the multiplier property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1408601-multiplier), which is for percent style set to 100 by default.

Comment: How is this different compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: Provided context for links